# Change position of tablesorter icon at runtime

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3, tablesorter

I'm using the jQueryUI tablesorter plugin with Bootstrap.  I have a table with one column right-aligned.  I'd like the sort icon for that column to appear on the left side of the header as opposed to the right side.  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need your custom css to override (have higher specificity) the bootstrap theme definitions.

Since no HTML was provided, [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/njj5b5vc/25/) right aligns all the `tbody` content of the "English" column and left aligns the icon, of the cell in the `thead`.

```
tr td:nth-child(4) {
    text-align: right;
}
.tablesorter-bootstrap .tablesorter-header:nth-child(4) .tablesorter-header-inner {
    padding-right: 4px;
    padding-left: 18px;
}
.tablesorter-bootstrap .tablesorter-header:nth-child(4) i.tablesorter-icon {
    left: 2px;
    right: auto;
}
```

Comment: I actually used the following selectors to get it to work: `th.text-right .tablesorter-header-inner` and `th.text-right i.tablesorter-icon`.